# Strapi is in production mode, editing content types is disabled

Tags: strapi

I ran into a problem, I want to create new types / components in **Content-Type Builder** in the Strapi admin panel. However, I get the message: "*Strapi is in production mode, editing content types is disabled. Please switch to development mode by starting your server with strapi develop.*" This error is expected and its solution seems logical - switch to development mode. BUT, I can't solve it.

strapi v4.10.6, node v16.13.0

I tried to run command `yarn develop`. Project started successfully and I got message  *Environment | development* from table in terminal and url localhost:1337/admin. Everything works, but I still can't create new types and get that error-message "*Strapi is in production mode,...*"
I tried to run `npm i`, `yarn build`
I tried change url from mywebsite.com to localhost in config/server.js. Also I have folder config/env/production.
Prod is started with command pm2 start 'NODE_ENV=production yarn start' and Prod is constantly running

Answer (score 1):

`yarn start` is for production, only content manger
`yarn develop` is for dev, content editor and content manager

Hope it makes more clear.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue but was able to resolve it by simply clearing the browser cache in Firefox using an extension called Clear Cache. After clearing the cache and refreshing the page, I was able to edit the content types in Strapi. I hope it resolves the issue for you as well.

Comment: I solved this issue with PM2 by running the command: `pm2 start 'NODE_ENV=development yarn start'`

Comment: Hi @NickWide,

I tried your solution of running the command and it worked wonderfully for me too. Thank you for sharing. It definitely presents a more effective and less tedious solution to the issue.

Answer (score 0):

simple solution
use this command
***npm run develop***